# Qualcoom Athereos Bluetooth adapter, automatically accept any incoming file?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I've bought a Lenovo C50-30 and I've upgraded it to Windows 10.

I'm trying to make it accept any incoming file from bluetooth without having to accept any single file.
I have tried looking in the settings of the bluetooth but I can't find anything useful.

How can I do?